# Why my uitableview getting stretched when displaying hundreds of record in ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, ipad, uitableview

This is the code that i am using to display my tableview custom cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

CustomeCellHome *cell = (CustomeCellHome *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomeCellHome" owner:self options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
            cell =  (CustomeCellHome *) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}

    NSString *strImgUrl = [[[[myarray valueForKey:@"mykey1"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"url"] objectAtIndex:0];
    [[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader] cancelLoadingImagesForTarget:cell.imgView];
    cell.imgView.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strImgUrl];

    cell.lbl1.text = [[myarray valueForKey:@"mykey2"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lbl2.text = [[myarray valueForKey:@"mykey3"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.lbl3.text = [[myarray valueForKey:@"mykey3"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lbl4.text = [[myarray valueForKey:@"mykey4"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.lbl5.text = [[myarray valueForKey:@"mykey5"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lbl6.text = [[myarray valueForKey:@"mykey6"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

CustomeCellHome is sub class of UITableViewCell and i am using Nib to display it. CustomeCellHome have all the IBOutlet and connected to Nib. All IBOutlet is property and synthesize and i have released that in dealloc method.

I am displaying 50 records in tableview at a time. If user want to see more record he can see that by clicking on next button and also view the previous record by clicking on previous button.

When user presses next button i am calling web service and getting next 50 record from the server. I am keeping my previous 50 records in the array and adding this new records to that array. But in "myarray" i am keeping only 50 at a time to display in tableview (Means i am displaying 50 records only at a time).

When i reach to view the 850 to 900 or near to that record my table view is getting stretched and it will stopped and displaying after some time.

Also after viewing 1450 to 1500 or near to that record i am receiving memory warning and my app getting crashed. I am not getting this. Why is it so ?

I have checked with memory tool i didn't get any memory leak. Am i using wrong to display the custom cell or my web service call causes more memory ?

Please any one can guide me for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you need to keep all the records, when you already have a webservice to get them?

Comment: it is not necessary to keep records. But i am keeping those to just reducing web service call. When user click on previous i am getting previous record from the array instead of calling web service.

Comment: is your service call taking too much of a time or create any performance issues?

If not, then why do you need to store them? After all you are displaying only 50 sets of data at a time.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are consuming too much memory. You don't need to leak memory to have your app shot by the watchdog.

I would profile the memory consumption of your app as you load more and more data. You'll probably want to respond to a `memoryWarning` message and delete all of your objects except for the current set. You could (de)serialize the objects to disc to preserve user's bandwidth.

You don't show the lifespan of your objects, but assuming they are fetched/stored in your `UI(Table)ViewController` you'll want to implement code in `- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning` or `- (void)viewDidUnload` (iOS5 vs. iOS6) to clear out the older data.

SideNote: is `myarray` actually a dictionary? It's good practice to give your variables descriptive names to make your code easier to understand (for others, and yourself in 2 months when you need to fix a bug).